# Proper database schema

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(c.cost)
from (select x.num as x, y.num as y, max(priority) as maxpriority
      from numbers x cross join
           numbers y join
           costs c
           on x.num between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and y.num between c.y and c.y + c.deltay
      where x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
            y.value between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
      group by x.num, y.num
    ) xyp join
    costs c
    on xyp.x between c.x and c.x + c.deltax and xyp.y between c.y + c.deltay and
        xyp.maxpriority = c.priority
```

I have been given this as an answer when looking for a "cost" between two points in a database populated by areas with every area having a different cost. I have been trying to get this to work along with figuring out the database schema, currently I'm getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'x.value' in 'where clause'` with

```
Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  num int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

As numbers and

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  x   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 2  y   int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 3  deltax  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 4  deltay  int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
 5  priority    int(11)         No  None          Change      Drop    Browse distinct values     More
```

As costs. Have been trying to figure this out for a while so big thanks to anyone for pointers.

Okay it doesn't throw an error now but it returns null instead of the cost within a selected area.

Answer (score 2):

Your `numbers` table does not have a column called `value` and you are trying to reference a column that does not exist so you get an error. Your current code:

```
where x.value between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
```

I am guessing that you want to use `num` instead:

```
where x.num between PIXELX and PIXELX and DELTAX and
      y.num between PIXELY and PIXELY and DELTAY
```

Comment: now I'm getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'c.costs' in 'field list'`

Comment: @user2279927 Do you have a column called `costs`?

Comment: Fixed it, now I'm not getting the proper results. Getting "null" instead of the real value within an area.

Comment: @user2279927 You will have to expand on your original post because _not getting proper results_ is not helpful.